# Batch rename in Windows according to external list

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Let's say I have a list of potential directory names that I want changed. there is no specific rule, it's just a matter of "switching from an old list of names" to "a new list of names"

For example, I want :
- the directory "A" (if it exists) to be renamed to "LEA"
- the directory "ON" (if it exists) to be renamed to "ONS"
- etc..., this for a list of ~100 potential names.

(other directories and files untouched of course).

I want to make it a batch because this will have to be done on a lot of different computers.

What do you think would be the best approach to do that ? Using Windows batch/powershell is fine. You can consider having the list of names in an external .txt file if you want.

Comment: read youir file line after line (`for /?`) and rename (`ren /?`). Redirect possible errors ("does not exist") to nul (`2>nul`)

Comment: If you can control the input file format, instead of having the external text file contain a hundred lines of `old1, new1`, have it contain a hundred lines of `move old1 new1`. And have it save as .bat instead of .txt. Search and replace once in a half decent text editor will sort it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple batch script would do it:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in (input.txt) do move "%%i" "%%j"
```

or if you care about missing directory error messages

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in (input.txt) do if exist "%%i" (move "%%i" "%%j")
```

The double `%%` is for escaping in a batch script. If you're just typing this in on the command line, you only need `%`

Input.txt should contain something like

```
A/LEA
ON/ONS
```

Using / (for example) as a delimiter in "`delims=/`" lets you have spaces in the directory names. If you don't have spaces, you can leave that out and spaces and tabs act as the default delimiters.

Comment: You are my god. Thank you ! :)

Comment: What if I want to specify this to happen in a different folder than the one I'm running the script from ? i've tried `set picdir="D:\some path with spaces\test\"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in (set_names.txt) do if exist "%%picdir%%i" (move "%%picdir%%i" "%%picdir%%j")`

Comment: Ok, found it myself :`for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in (set_names.txt) do if exist "%picdir%%%i" (move "%picdir%%%i" "%picdir%%%j")`

Answer (score 0):

use a csv file named

Content of this csv file :

```
 oldnamedir;newnamedir
 data;newdata
 data2;newdata2
```

Do a PowerShell script :

```
   $mycsv=import-csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "c:\temp\myfilewithreplace.csv"
   $startdir="C:\dir_where_you_want_rename_dirs"

   foreach ($row in $mycsv)
   {
     $listdirtorename= gci -Path $startdir -Directory -Recurse | where { ($_.FullName -split "\\" | select -last 1) -eq ($row.oldnamedir)  }  | select Name, FullName, @{N="LenghtName";E={($_.FullName -split "\\").Count}} | sort LenghtName -Descending 

      foreach ($dir in $listdirtorename)
      {
        rename-item -Path $dir.FullName -NewName $row.newnamedir -Force
      }
   }
```